# Performing bounding box query in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, performance, geography-data-type

I have a PostgreSQL table, with almost 2 million rows, with a long-lat `coordinates` field in the form `POINT(-73.4938 33.2405)`.

Supposing there's a geospatial index on that field, what's the most efficient, fastest way to select all the rows within an arbitrary bounding box?

The box is like `SW long-lat: -74.0042 40.7688`, `NE long-lat: -73.8809 40.7984`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Assuming the given bounding box limits are in the same spatial reference system as the stored coordinates, and you know which spatial operator (intersects or contained by) you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  coordinates 
    && -- intersects,  gets more rows  -- CHOOSE ONLY THE
    @ -- contained by, gets fewer rows -- ONE YOU NEED!
    ST_MakeEnvelope (
        xmin, ymin, -- bounding 
        xmax, ymax, -- box limits
        my_srid)
```

Alternatively, if you prefer the sound of "contains" (instead of "contained by") the `WHERE` clause should be flipped:

```
WHERE  ST_MakeEnvelope (...)
    ~ -- contains, gets same fewer rows 
    coordinates
```

PS: Given (by OP after the above was posted) that the records *are* simple points, I think that the *difference* between "intersects" and "containment" becomes very subtle, affecting only the points *on the edges* of the bounding box.

Comment: that's a good point. Contains should be fine, since you won't really be able to see a map marker if it's _on_ the boundary (ie, the browser chrome probably).

Comment: `What's the fastest ...?` : OP

Comment: Be aware: `&&` and `@` don't seem to work when intersecting with polygon Geometry. In this case, use `ST_Intersects(latlng_column,ST_GeomFromText('Polygon ((...))',4326))` or alternatively `ST_Contains`

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT ST_Y(the_geom) AS latitude, ST_X(the_geom) as longitude
from units u where the_geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(left, bottom, right, top, 4326)
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried both ST_MakeEnvelope vs the maths compare of "x > min_x and x < max_x and y > min_y and y < max_y" ...on average ST_MakeEnvelope took 60ms and maths compare took 155ms on my particular bbox query.

So the spatial search ST_MakeEnvelope should be faster than maths compare!

Comment: Actually, if you create the right indexes min_x, max_x, min_y and max_y will be much faster. I have a very large dataset (over 3 million polygons) and did both `INDEX` over ST_MakeEnvelope and (ST_XMax, ST_XMin, ST_YMax, ST_YMin) and the difference is hugely in favor to math. Math took me less than 20s (INDEX + Query) while Envelope intersection took over 2min (I gave up when it reached 2min, 40s only for Spatial indexing)

Comment: @caiohamamura "create the right indexes" would you elaborate with an answer to this question?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is still true, when I first comment it was still in PostgreSQL 10 and not sure which PostGIS version. Probably this still holds true, since envelope will perform more checks than simply math. 

The indexes you need to create are [BTREE](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-indexes) for the `x`, `y` coordinates, and for the `coordinates` (provided you convert it to geometry with [ST_GeomFromText](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html)) your only option is [GIST](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html).