# Look Up table from (Latitude,Longitude) to country, city etc. boundaries (Bounding Box)

Tags: postgis, geocoding, extents, administrative-boundaries

I'm looking for "Standard" assume file (?) containing best practice used simple "approximately squared" boundaries of countries, major cities etc.

The use case is getting (Lat,Lon) and perform look up search versus this static file.

If there is such ESRI shapefile etc. to put in PostGIS DB and then perform some query for this - That's also valid.

Comment: Open street map is a good place to start. You can extract the bounding boxes from the country and builtup area boundaries... this is a rough search right? You want to know roughly what country/city you're in before querying your geometries... I'm sure there's a postGIS way of doing this like http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83387/whats-the-fastest-way-to-do-a-bounding-box-query-in-postgis

Comment: [this](http://www.gadm.org/) is a decent coverage of country, and regional divisions. You can load this into a PostGIS table with a GiST index. However, what it calls a "City" boundary depends on the region level.