# query amenity and bounding box

Tags: postgis, osm2pgsql, overpass-api, bbox

I'm trying to query specific amenities in a specific region on a postGIS database.

I'd like to be able to select multiple amenities in the query, and output their OSM ID, type, lat, lon, & name.

For example:

a nice query on amenity:

```
SELECT osm_id,ST_X(ST_TRANSFORM(way,4674)) AS X, ST_Y(ST_TRANSFORM(way,4674)) as Y,name
from planet_osm_point where amenity='school' limit 5;
```

I can't get any results from a [bounding box search](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/83387/93486), and that's part of the problem:

```
/*with "bbox() ~ way"*/
SELECT osm_id,ST_X(ST_TRANSFORM(way,4674)) AS X, ST_Y(ST_TRANSFORM(way,4674)) as Y,name
from planet_osm_point where ST_MakeEnvelope(-125.0011, 24.9493, -66.9326, 49.5904, 4326) ~ way limit 5;

/*with "way @ st_MakeEnvelope()"*/
SELECT osm_id,ST_X(ST_TRANSFORM(way,4674)) AS X, ST_Y(ST_TRANSFORM(way,4674)) as Y,name
from planet_osm_point where way @ ST_MakeEnvelope(-125.0011, 24.9493, -66.9326, 49.5904, 4326) limit 5;
```

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Thetoxicarcade/f68fd215ade2c750ea76a9a69c8531c1) with a bunch of example queries I've tried to make work on the DBs.

Comment: Related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83387/whats-the-fastest-way-to-do-a-bounding-box-query-in-postgis @ST_Contains

Comment: @Mapperz - Neither `SELECT osm_id,ST_X(ST_TRANSFORM(way,4674)) AS X, ST_Y(ST_TRANSFORM(way,4674)) as Y,name
from planet_osm_point where way @ ST_MakeEnvelope(-125.0011, 24.9493, -66.9326, 49.5904, 4326) limit 5;` nor `SELECT osm_id,ST_X(ST_TRANSFORM(way,4674)) AS X, ST_Y(ST_TRANSFORM(way,4674)) as Y,name
from planet_osm_point where ST_MakeEnvelope(-125.0011, 24.9493, -66.9326, 49.5904, 4326) ~ way limit 5;` return results.

Comment: your using 4674 https://epsg.io/4674 and your bounds limits are -122.19 -59.87m,-25.28,32.72  I see a mistake in your bbox.

Comment: @Mapperz Thank you! I ended up using `SELECT osm_id,ST_X(ST_TRANSFORM(way,4674)) AS X, ST_Y(ST_TRANSFORM(way,4674)) as Y,name
from planet_osm_point where (amenity='school' OR amenity='fire_station') AND ST_TRANSFORM(way,4674) @ ST_MakeEnvelope(-125.0011, 24.9493, -66.9326, 49.5904, 4674) limit 5;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering from the comments.

My mistake was using the wrong coordinates system, everyting should have been in epsg/4674.

```
SELECT osm_id,ST_X(ST_TRANSFORM(way,4674)) AS X, ST_Y(ST_TRANSFORM(way,4674)) as Y,name
from planet_osm_point where
(amenity='school' OR amenity='fire_station')
AND ST_TRANSFORM(way,4674)
@
ST_MakeEnvelope(-125.0011, 24.9493, -66.9326, 49.5904, 4674) limit 5;
```