# Locating geometries within a polygon/area

Tags: postgis, linestring

I have a postgis database table of boundary data which is made up of LineString geometry's, what I would like to do is create a query that will return only the rows that contain a LineString geometry that is within (or at least one point of the LineString is within) a given polygon or area (this would typically be a bounding polygon of the current map view).

I've tried using ST_Intersects, ST_Contains and ST_Covers but to no success. What is the recommended method for doing this?

Comment: A plain ST_Intersects should work. What did you try?

Comment: I have a feeling it may have been due to the parameter I was using with it (converting GeoJSON to Geometry with ST_GeomFromGeoJSON as one of the parameters). I've since used ST_MakeEnvelope with coordinate points and the && operator to represent the intersection and it seems to return the results I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this via the answer of [Performing bounding box query in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83387/performing-bounding-box-query-in-postgis) by using a bounding box via ST_MakeEnvelope