# Accessing PostGIS geometry with psycopg2

Tags: postgis, postgresql, query, psycopg2

I've a PostGIS database loaded with several tables filled with shapefiles. I'm using psycopg2 to access everything via python. I'm able to access the table names with the below query:

```
"""SELECT table_name 
              FROM information_schema.tables 
              WHERE table_schema = 'public'"""
```

which returns

```
('Sea Areas(PolyGrid)',)
('geography_columns',)
('geometry_columns',)
('spatial_ref_sys',)
('12NM(LineGrid)',)
('TimeZone(LineGrid)',)
('12NM_PolyGrid',)
```

But when i try and run a simple query like:

```
"""SELECT geom FROM 12NM_PolyGrid"""
```

it throws:

```
Error while connecting to PostgreSQL syntax error at or near "12"
```

I'm new to SQL so it could be simple error. Ultimately I would like to do a bounding box query like in [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83387/performing-bounding-box-query-in-postgis). The results would then be placed in a geodataframe.

Comment: Best practice is to use legal SQL identifiers in table and column names. This means leading alpha, with alpha-numeric or underscore in the remaking characters, *all lowercase*. This permits case-insensitive access to columns. Using mixed-case identifiers is poor practice and using leading numerics is an *antipattern*. Since you are new at SQL, this is the best time to stop a practice that will cause failure and pain down the line. Do not use any identifier which would require double-quoting, and you won't have to use double-quotes.

Comment: Note that, while shapefiles might have been the source, your database does *not* have "several tables filled with shapefiles". Shapefile is an ancient file-based data format. The act of loading them is to the PG database creates PostGIS geometry columns (alongside other column types) in tables -- the data is no longer in shapefile format, so it would be more correct to describe as "several tables filled *from* shapefiles".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostGreSQL (and thus PostGIS) don't like table (or column) names to start with digits or to have mixed case. So you need to add `"` around any name that does this. So, in your case the select statement is:

```
SELECT geom FROM "12NM_PolyGrid"
```

which in a python string should probably be:

```
'SELECT geom FROM "12NM_PolyGrid"'
```

Comment: Perfect, cheers Ian, must have been one of the few combinations I hadn’t tried!